# browse-url-at-point opens link text

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I have a link in my org file such as `[[https://google.com][mylink]]`. When I put the point over "mylink" and run `M-x browse-url-at-point` my browser opens "http://mylink.com".

Is there a different function or option I should be using to open the link url instead of the link text?

Comment: @Drew typo, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the function to call to browse a link in an org-mode file is `org-open-at-point` which is bound to `C-c C-o`.

Edit:
Regarding the follow-up question about opening an org-mode link in a secondary browser, using another function seems to work:

```
   (defun org-open-at-point-with-firefox ()                              
    (interactive)                                                         
    (let ((browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-firefox))              
     (org-open-at-point )))
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. So my actual end goal here is to define a shortcut which will open a link in a non-default browser. So I was actually using `browse-url-chrome` since my default browser is Firefox. I don't see any variants/options on `org-open-at-point` that would allow specifying that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there an org-mode bug for org-open-at-point not being able to handle a link where the text matches the URL?

Comment: there is a customizable association list `org-link-parameters` you could edit.  you could either change the lambda function passed to the `http` and `https` options to use `browse-url-chrome` or possibly add a new link type you could prefix with `chrome:path.to.site` or something like that.  i think the suggested answer is a good solution as well.

Comment: something like
`("chrome" :follow (lambda (path) (browse-url-chrome (concat "https:" path))))`

the downside to this is that you have to make your links specific to using chrome

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks @Realraptor

Comment: OP: Please consider either (1) splitting off the second question as a separate post - preferable if it's not strongly coupled with the first question or (2) integrating it into this post. Comments can be deleted at any time - Q & A need to stand alone, to help others. Thx.